# treeview Checking if node is selected

Tags: treeview, selected

I'm having a problem.

I'm creating a software that uses a treeview control, to select the OU, and depending of the OU you select, below is the action.

when I run the code below it gives me an error

```
 If TreeView1.SelectedNode.Nodes.Item(0) = True Then
    '..........................
 End If
```

the error is operator = is not defined for systems.windows.forms

how do I check if a certain node is selected, I'm using vb 2012.

Answer (score 0):

The TreeView class has a SelectedNode property which you can use.

```
TreeNode tn = TreeView1.SelectedNode;

if ( tn == null )
Console.WriteLine("No tree node selected.");
```